# Error when compiling using NPM

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

Im new to angularjs, i got a project file that is in angular framework which i am currently new, we actually have two files the one works fine but the other does not, they other project file has a .bin on it and works just fine, the other which we are currently tinkering has no .bin folder, how do we generate a .bin folder or how do we fix the error shown bellow:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the funct                                       ion or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol NgModul                                       e in C:/xampp/htdocs/my-app/node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/@angula                                       r/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol DataTablesModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/my-app/no                                       de_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.module.d.ts, resolving symb                                       ol DataTablesModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/my-app/node_modules/angular-datatables/sr                                       c/angular-datatables.module.d.ts

I get the error message "not a binary etc" when running `npm run ng serve`. so I copied the `bin` folder of a working application to the current application and it was able to run the command only I get the error message above upon doing so.

Here is the content of **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.1.0",
    "angular2-busy": "^2.0.3",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.4.53",
    "angulartics-google-analytics": "^0.4.0",
    "angulartics2": "^2.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.0.1",
    "ngDfp": "^0.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^6.5.6",
    "toastr-ng2": "^4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

when I run `npm start`, I am getting this error message:

```
$ npm start
```

> > my-app@0.0.0 start C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app
> >     ng serve
>
> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable
>   program or batch file.
>      npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE   npm ERR! errno 1
>     npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`     npm ERR! Exit status 1  npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 start script.   npm ERR! This
>   is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:    npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\lboadilla\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-05-24T05_42_53_038Z-debug.log

when i use the command **npm install** i get:

```
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-datatable@0.6.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-charts@1.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-charts@1.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angulartics-google-analytics@0.4.0 requires a peer of angulartics@^1.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN toastr-ng2@4.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN toastr-ng2@4.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@0.4.53 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@0.4.53 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@0.4.53 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-select@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-select@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular-2-dropdown-multiselect@1.3.2 requires a peer of tslib@^1.6.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN The package @types/datatables.net is included as both a dev and production dependency.
```

btw im using **windows**.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Are you aware of any building tool used in the app. The thing `ng serve` should most probably host your app on your browser provided there is a server attached to the application. I believe you must be having a `package.json` file in the app. Try posting what it says.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari thanks, ive added it for your reference, hope it helps

Comment: Its an Angular 2 application. I added a`angular` tag to your question.

Comment: Did u try running `npm start` at the root directory of this app ?

Comment: it says 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: You do not have to use `ng` in the command. Try hitting `npm start` only

Comment: ill add the error message above

Comment: Also not sure what `'ng' : 'ng'` does in package.json. Never used it before. I believe that too can be removed.

Comment: ill try removing the script section

Comment: Do not remove the entire section, you need it for your app. Just try removing `"ng":"ng"` line and then try running `npm start` on your console at root directory (i.e where `package.json` is)

Comment: this project *appears* to be an angular-cli project, but it would seem that you don't have angular-cli installed on your system.  try installing [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/).

Comment: @Claies agree with you , IF you are new to Angular please use cli its has a great tool to build a Project skeleton which is good for starters . please use that

Comment: @RahulSingh it's not about what is good or not good;  This project was created using angular-cli, which is where the `ng` command comes from.  If angular-cli isn't installed on the machine, `ng` won't be found, and this project won't run.

Comment: yup i was stressing on using cli for this you need to use the command npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: @Claies can you provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to install angular cli use the following command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Global package:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Local project package:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist # On Windows use rmdir /s /q node_modules dist
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
ng init
```

Comment: is this inside the project directory folder inline with package.json?

Comment: hi i get this message after installing it: `npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

Comment: This is not an error. It is a warning that fseventsd, which is Mac OS specific, cannot be installed on Linux.

There is no need to be alarmed, and the package that needs fsevents will still work - that's why it's an optional dependency.

Comment: can you try running it now

Comment: it also says: `npm WARN update-linked node_modules\@angular\cli needs updating to 1.0.4 from 1.1.0-beta.0 but we can't, as it's a symlink
` after i run `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: if i understand correctly, if i choose to do the local project package does that mean i need to run the command every new project that requires the angular-cli, or can i just copy the directory directly?

Comment: when you setup a new project using cli it will automatically get added you need not run the command again , npm insatll will do the trick

Comment: i got error when running `npm install` after `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: btw when i ran `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` it shows `npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.1 should be installed with -g`

Comment: its a global dependency so it says to be installed with -g

Comment: should i reinstall it?

Comment: yup do a clean uninstall of both global and local cli and cache clean and then install

Comment: i did not run all the commands, i thought i only need to run either global or local package and choose between them.

Comment: i ran the `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` command but it did not create a `dist` folder only `node_modules` there are bunch of errors like `gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2`, i dont know if they are just optional dependencies but im now running the next command to it as you have mentioned above.

Comment: i get the new error after running `npm instal`l, i still did not get ng to run in cmd. you may refer to the end of my post for the updated error message that i get after running all the comamnds that you mentioned.

Comment: is this a fresh project ?